# How to "clean" previous kernels after update?

Tags: 11.04, kernel, versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I to remove or hide old kernel versions, to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

I  know this topic was brought up many times but I didn't really found an answer that would satisfy me. 
Namely: I have just updated the kernel version (to 2.6.38-11) and I still have some "leftovers" from the previous version. That's the content of the /boot folder

```
abi-2.6.38-10-generic
abi-2.6.38-11-generic
config-2.6.38-10-generic
config-2.6.38-11-generic
grub
initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
System.map-2.6.38-10-generic
System.map-2.6.38-11-generic
vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-10-generic
vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-11-generic
vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic
```

I want to clean all the stuff that shouldn't be on my computer anymore as the new version of kernel works just fine. I was trying to clean it up with use Synaptic but I get this : 
[image]

EDIT : 
When I for instance update grub I still get this even with removed dependencies :

```
$ sudo update-grub2
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
done
```

I want to get rid of these images.