# delete GRUB ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, kernel, grub2

how do I delete grub on Ubuntu 11.10. I want to get into ubuntu normally without having to choose which operating system I would run. and how to remove ubuntu with older kernels as shown below

[grub](http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/9249/cuplikanlayarpada201202.png)

Comment: Grub is a bootloader, don't delete it, unless you want the system to become unbootable. To remove old kernel versions, -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/65096/how-to-clean-previous-kernels-after-update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not delete or remove grub as grub is responsible for booting.

You can, however, configure grub to hide the menu.

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

```
# Graphical 
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

# command line
sudo -e /etc/default/grub
```

And edit or add these lines

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=X
>
> X is a positive integer (e.g. 1, 5, 10, etc)
>
> The boot process will pause and display a blank screen or the designated splash >image for X seconds. At the end of the time period, the system will boot. No menu will >be displayed.
>      While GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is active, the menu can be displayed by pressing any >key.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Hidden

In terms of old kernels, remove them. either from the command line of software center.

[How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

Answer (score 1):

Also, there seems to be some graphical utility called [StartUpManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager) which allows to set the menu timeout and other settings:

[image: StartUpManager]