# My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room

Tags: upgrade, apt, partitioning

My first issue was when I tried to `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade`. On upgrade I get the following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried running apt-get install -f and this was the output(after saying yes on prompt)

```
(Reading database ... 186183 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic_3.2.0-27.43_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic_3.2.0-27.43_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/System.map-3.2.0-27-generic': No space left on device
 No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dpkg-deb:    error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-27-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic_3.2.0-27.43_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried running `apt-get autoremove` and it gives me the same error as `apt-get upgrade`.

When I run `df`, I get this for `/boot`:

```
/dev/sda1                    233191     230297         0 100% /boot
```

So, I read elsewhere that I should try to purge old kernels. I checked for what kernels I had with:

```
$ dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-2.6.38-13-server  2.6.38-13.52  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-13-server   3.0.0-13.22   Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0  on x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-14-server   3.0.0-14.23   Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0  on x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-15-server   3.0.0-15.26   Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0  on x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-16-server   3.0.0-16.29   Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0  on x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-17-server   3.0.0-17.30   Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0  on x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic  3.2.0-24.39   Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0  on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic  3.2.0-25.40   Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0  on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic  3.2.0-26.41   Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0  on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

When I try to remove the oldest with this:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.38-13-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic but it is not going to be     installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I free up or extend boot without messing up my installation?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: @dskrvk Yes! Why is `Remove-Unused-Dependencies` not the default?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

### Freeing Up Space on the Root File System

To free up space on the root file system you can try to execute `apt-get clean`.

If that doesn't work you can go to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and manually remove a few files from the cache to get some space back, e.g.:

```
sudo rm linux-headers-*
```

It won't hurt to remove all of the `.deb` files here if you need to - that is what `apt-get clean` does. They will be automatically be re-downloaded by `apt` if they are needed again.

### Freeing Up Space on the /boot File System

The Original Poster has a separate `/boot` partition, and that is what is full and preventing the `apt` system from working. It will be necessary for him to free up space there.

If there almost enough space, go to `/boot` and remove a config file or two:

```
sudo rm config-3.2.0-19-generic-pae
```

for example, but using the name of one of the kernel versions you intend to remove anyway. This will free up a little space (about 144K apiece).

If you need more space individually remove old `vmlinuz`, `initrd`, `abi` and `System.map` files until you have enough space (about 22M for one of my i386 kernel versions).

Whatever you do, *don't remove them all*. You should at least keep the latest two matching versions of each kind of file, for each kind of kernel you use.

Then proceed with your apt-get install commands. As mentioned above they may have to re-download some of the debs you deleted, but if so that will happen automatically. When you have apt working again, clean up by using apt-get to remove the packages corresponding to the files you removed - so everything matches.

---

The config file in `/boot` is the kernel config that *was used* by the kernel team to *build* the kernel of the same name. It should be harmless to remove unless you want it for reference or to aid you in building your own kernels.

Finally you are manually removing an old kernel package or two from the `/boot` partition to make even more room for the new one.

Comment: I tried removing almost all the configs. It still doesn't seem to have enough space. What other files in there would be safe to remove?

My root file system isn't anywhere near full, so I'm not worried about it.

Comment: I updated my answer with the further files to remove by hand. It seems to me that removing the 3.0.0.13 and 3.0.0.14 sets (five files to the set including the abi file) would suffice.

Comment: Why not just remove **all** the files in `/var/cache/apt/archives`? (`sudo apt-get clean` will do this, or you can do it manually.) Please note that I am **not** suggesting to remove all files in `/boot`.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I've edited the answer to suggest trying apt-get clean first, but I'm note sure whether it works in thies condition or not. It won't help the OP but might help others without separate /boot partitions. I tried to go from the least aggresive steps to the most aggressive.

Comment: @EliahKagan I would too, but the OP won't have any .deb files in his /boot partition to remove. The OP has to go all the way to removing some old kernels by hand. See his comment above (the first one). I'll make another edit suggesting that all the .deb files in the cache can be removed.

Comment: This fixed it. I realized it would probably come down to removing files by hand, but I'm always hesitant to do that with anything installed by apt, so I thought I'd ask here first.

Comment: I would like to add that a similar issue may happen ith /usr/src (when /usr is on separate partition of course). I have dealt with such an issue by moving directories of old kernels out of there.

Comment: Do not use `sudo rm` to remove from /boot. Instead, use `sudo dpkg --purge` to remove some old linux-image package. Thereafter use `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix the broken dependency.

Comment: Though sometime system may be so full that even dpkg can not operate. But `rm` can be used then.

Comment: even though your answers is accepted, it is a very bad solution. you can easily end up with an unbootable system. and you don't even offer a solution on what to delete. you should consider deleting this answer.

Answer (score 71):

In my case, the `apt` commands and `dpkg` command could not finish, and could not remove.
The autoupdate had failed on installing `2.6.32-56-server`.

My first step, was to identify space to be used,

```
cd /boot
du -sk *|sort -n
```

I had about 30 kernels and supporting files.

I did a `uname -a` to get the running kernel,
I identified that I was on  Linux alternate `2.6.32-43-server` and did a `tar` of 6 of the versions that were not running, and were old.

```
tar -cvf ~username/boot.tar *2.6.32-44-server *2.6.32-45-server *2.6.32-46-server *2.6.32-47-server *2.6.32-48-server *2.6.32-49-server
```

I then did a `rm -rf` of what I had backed up:

```
rm -rf *2.6.32-44-server *2.6.32-45-server *2.6.32-46-server *2.6.32-47-server *2.6.32-48-server *2.6.32-49-server
```

I am showing these commands as examples, you will have to decide what you will work with for your situation.

Now that I had some space on `/boot`, I was able to run

```
apt-get -f install
```

To clean up the failed install of `2.6.32-56-server`.

I then did a

```
apt-get remove linux-headers-2.6.32-38 linux-headers-2.6.32-38-server linux-image-2.6.32-38-server
apt-get remove linux-headers-2.6.32-39 linux-headers-2.6.32-39-server linux-image-2.6.32-39-server
```

This gave me room to put back what I had backed up.

```
tar -xf ~username/boot.tar
rm  ~username/boot.tar
```

To clean up, I then could run:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

I rebooted and am now down to using 4% of `/boot`.

Comment: This was the most helpful for me out of all of the suggestions.  Thank you very much!

Comment: removing files from /boot just horribly breaks apt and dpkg since thier install and removal scripts fail HARD when the files are missing. I don't see how you got this to work.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `dpkg` instead of `apt-get` to remove older kernels:

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic
```

Comment: Maybe there are plusses for using this, but @mreiter's suggestion worked for me when this one didn't (this one was suggested on ubuntu's IRC support channel.)

Comment: @AaronHall This answer simply contains the key part of [mreiter’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/205776/250300) (the last line) and it’s much shorter since it does not cover cleaning of headers (which does not help in the case of separate `/boot` partition).

Comment: A couple of reminders: use `uname -r` to know the kernel that you **must NOT remove** (the one you're currently using).

Also, when you're done removing old kernels, remember to run `apt-get -f install` to fix possible broken dependencies.

Comment: This option fails if `/boot` has no space left

Answer (score 10):

I noticed there were still some files of the old versions in the boot directory:

```
$ ls /boot
vmcoreinfo-2.6.31-17-server
```

And the package manager would list the old versions:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

I therefore used this command (`autoremove` would also remove more recent images I don't want to remove)

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.31-17-server
```

I had still some headers left:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
```

So I did this:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-2.6.32-34
```

Finally there was one package left I couldn't remove with apt-get purge:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-2.6.28-11-server
```

Source: [Remove a package marked as rc by dpkg](http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/remove-package-marked-rc/)

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-2.6.28-11-server
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that the only thing that worked for me was using Aptitude.

```
sudo aptitude
```

Then when it opens it will usually say something about unmet dependencies on the bottom. You can hit the letter `g` to proceed with the suggested removal. It will take you to a page where it lists what is going to happen.

There should be a minus `-` next to the broken kernels. Press `g` again and it will remove the broken kernels. Press `q` to quit. Then you should be able to use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the old kernels and free up space.

**UPDATE 2022:**
Another way is to manually remove some kernel files, especially if aptitude isn't installed:

First check your running kernel to make sure you don't delete it:

```
uname -r
```

Then list the modules directory:

```
ls /usr/lib/modules/
```

For example, here is a list from one of my servers:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar  2 14:16 5.4.0-100-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 Apr 27  2021 5.4.0-26-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 May 13  2021 5.4.0-28-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 Oct 26 14:01 5.4.0-72-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 Oct 26 14:01 5.4.0-73-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 Oct 26 14:01 5.4.0-80-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 Mar 11 16:20 5.4.0-84-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 Mar 11 16:20 5.4.0-89-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  250 Mar 11 16:20 5.4.0-91-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb  1 14:15 5.4.0-97-generic
```

Remove all but the newest 2 from this directory. For example:

```
sudo rm -rf 5.4.0-26-generic 5.4.0-28-generic 5.4.0-72-generic 5.4.0-73-generic 5.4.0-80-generic 5.4.0-84-generic 5.4.0-89-generic 5.4.0-91-generic
```

Also check the /boot directory and do the same process there.

Then check to see if some space was freed up:

```
df -h
```

Finally run apt to fix the broken packages:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: this is the ONLY valid answer. all of the other answers didn't worked, as the package manager wanted to install a package before it could remove anything.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot act upon packages, but you *can* act upon other files. First, go through your home folder and see whether there is *anything* you can delete. If not, try to move a good amount of files to another partition (or a flash drive) and then try `sudo apt-get install -f` to clean up the package dependency issues (most likely you installed a .deb file through `dpkg`), and then purge any old kernels. Once you safely have at least 10 MB, try purging unneeded software or files.

Comment: The home folder is not in /boot

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-xxxx
```

Do that for all old kernels and only keep the most recent two.

If you want to automatically remove the old kernels and update GRUB
see this: [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you don't mind cleaning up everything, you don't even need to specify the Linux image.

Comment: I tried this option to remove old kernels  (more specifically the one suggested in the Ubuntu documentation, i.e. `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`) but it fails because `/boot` has no space left (which was also the case in the original question)

Answer (score 2):

Check the use of `/var/tmp` with `du -sh /var/tmp/`. All files in that folder can be deleted to make space.

You can then run the following to remove the old kernels:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt install byobu
sudo purge-old-kernels
sudo apt autoremove
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: What does `/var/tmp` have to do with old kernels? And it is not always safe to delete everything in `/var/tmp`...

Comment: IIRC newer versions of byobu do not have purge-old-kernels script. Besides, you could not install byobu, if /boot is full and if there are broken dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Install [linux-purge](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge/) tool like [this](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge/+announcement/15313).

Then run this in terminal:

```
sudo linux-purge --clear-boot --fix
```

Then go on removing kernels by e.g.

```
sudo linux-purge --keep 1 --choose
```

Extra:

If I recall correctly there is a default setting in Ubuntu 18.04 and later for unattended-upgrades that removes unneeded kernels, but it can not cope with the case that system is already full: The setting is `Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages true`.

If you want to use linux-purge for unattended kernel removal instead of using unattended-upgrades for that, you should disable removing unused kernels by editing  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades or preferably an overriding separate file (e.g. /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/52unattended-upgrades-local); that means [at least](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/issues/246) setting

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies false;
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages false;
```

Thereafter set up a systemd service executing

```
/usr/local/bin/linux-purge --auto-only --keep 1 --yes
```

whenever you want.

Comment: OP cant install anything if its full

Comment: @alchemy usually it is just separate /boot partition that is full. Besides this does not need package manager for installing.

Comment: The BEST and EASIEST solution! Thanks a lot. Saved

Answer (score 1):

Use Synaptic Package Manager. Just pick the package you want removed and it will prompt you to also remove packages that depend on it. In my experience, kernel packages always come in groups of two (or more, depending on how you count) that are interdependant. You can usually find old ones quickly by using the "local/obsolete" filter.

Comment: E.g. on a (text-only) server, there is no Synaptic. So not really a viable solution for servers.

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

Source: [I get this error after upgade. please help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360023/i-get-this-error-after-upgade-please-help)

Comment: what does sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a this do? 
On Ubuntu 16 its says unknown option -a

Comment: For this question, `apt` will fail to remove kernel packages because the removal process itself generates files in `/boot`, which is already full. That's why `apt-get autoremove` fails. The question you're looking for is https://askubuntu.com/q/142926/158442, which already has `autoremove`, listed.

Comment: @muru I just posted it because it did the trick, for me :D

Comment: I'm sure it did, what I'm saying is that your problem would have been the other question, not this one.

Comment: @muru oh ok got it :D

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting with this issue from time to time, and still haven't seen any solution that actually does the full job. In some cases, removing old kernels ends up in dependencies that stops me from removing anything and I had to remove kernels manually from /boot. However, I still wanted apt to do the full job as I imagine the manually deleted kernels are logged somewhere and may cause future  problems, when something reports files missing because of me sitting doing rm -rf on files.

So I wrote this script, based on many googled suggestions here that doesn't require any further installation of something. The script has been modified a few times to support some my own "unexpected" situations. For example, running this on a raspberry pi, update-grub probably don't exists. And in some cases when running the last updaters, the servers was stuck with IPv6 where some sites was unreachable.

The script figures out whether it has to forcefully remove kernels that is completly stuck due to dependency builds, ot if it can do it the "right" way.

```
#!/bin/bash

ipv4="-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true"

if [ "$1" = "4" ] ; then
    withip=$ipv4
    echo "Going IPv4 ($withip)"
fi

echo "Autoremove+Purge."
apt-get $withip -y -f autoremove --purge >/dev/null 2>&1

if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
    echo "Auto Removal Failed!"
fi

echo "Old dependency fix."
apt-get $withip -f -y install >/dev/null 2>&1

if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
    echo "That failed. So we'll try to make up to it during this process."
fi

echo "Now, going old kernel cleanup!"
kern=$(dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r`)
hadErrors=0

for k in $kern
do
    echo apt-get -y purge $k
    apt-get $withip -y purge $k >/dev/null 2>&1

    if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
        echo "Failed apt-purge... Using plan B (--force-all -P)..."
        dpkg --force-all -P $k >/dev/null 2>&1
        echo "Rerunning stuff (apt-get -f -y install) for dependencies..."
        apt-get $withip -f -y install >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
            echo "Still failing..."
            hadErrors=1
        fi
    fi
done

if [ "$hadErrors" = "1" ] ; then
    echo "I had errors. I should rerun this process, to see if there are more kernels that were left out after cleanup..."
    /usr/local/tornevall/cleankernel
fi

apt-get $withip autoremove
apt-get $withip update
apt-get $withip upgrade
apt-get $withip dist-upgrade

grb=$(which update-grub)
if [ "" != "$grb" ] ; then
    update-grub
else
    echo "Can't upgrade grub since update-grub is missing..."
fi
```

Comment: Did you try [linux-purge](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge/)? It does not have that Force IPv4 thing currently, though.

Comment: Your script would purge linux-image-generic in my system, which is bad.

Comment: They are for some reason being put back when the old kernels has been cleaned up. At least this has been the case for me ever since I built this script. However, this script is something I use when there are no other options to proceed forward. Normally, the upgrades are taking care of this by themselves, but when it comes to this moment, when nothing else works, this may be a good option as there usually comes more kernels that will be set up after the cleanup. If this good or bad is probably discussable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by mreiter is good, but a bit old. Here's my take on freeing up space on /boot and removing old kernels in general:

First check which kernel version you are currently using:

```
uname -r
```

In my case I got:

```
5.11.0-41-generic
```

List your installed kernel versions:

```
apt list --installed linux-image*
```

In my case this gave:

```
linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic  <-- Can be removed
linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic  <-- In use. Don't remove
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04  <-- Meta package. Don't remove
```

**Don't purge the kernel version currently in use! Don't purge packages starting with "linux-image-generic".** These are meta packages to provide updated kernels. You can now purge (remove including extra / config files) all kernel versions including their modules and headers you are **not** using:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic linux-modules-5.11.0-40-generic linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic
```

apt will tell you what packages it will actually remove. Make sure none of them include your current kernel version. Grub should be updated automatically.

Now you might still have some leftover kernel configs in /boot. You can check this using:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep rc | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V
```

If this lists any packages, purge all of them using:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep rc | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

To clean everything else up, run:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt clean
```

which should auto-remove unused packages and clean up downloaded packages

Comment: This is an _excellent_ answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply running `sudo apt-get -f autoremove` resolved my problem.

Comment: Did you have 100% disk space /boot usage?

Comment: Looking at my monitoring history, it didn't seem to. PS: I am on Vagrant xenial, and my boot file system `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a couple articles on /boot being full which is not solved by dpkg purging old linux kernels, because *apt-get -f install* or *apt-get -f autoremov*e reinstalls the kernels.

In my case, at least, the signed and extra packages also needed to be removed - the kernels were dependencies for these packages so apt reinstalled them. Generally, related kernel packages should be purged before calling 'install'. If you tried to *apt-get upgrade* right after purging, the error message should have said which packages had an unmet dependency of the kernel you'd just purged.

In my case, the following tactic worked:

```
#as sudo, repeat 1-3 for any old kernels; can be scripted
dpkg --force-all -P linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic 
dpkg --purge linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
dpkg --purge linux-signed-image-4.4.0-112-generic
apt-get -f install #dependency resolution didn't have work to do for kernel packages
apt-get autoremove --purge -f 
apt-get autoclean
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple steps to resolve an issue, when /boot is 100% full:

This is a really good article:
https://gist.github.com/ipbastola/2760cfc28be62a5ee10036851c654600

### TL/DR:

Determine which linux images you have installed:

```
dpkg -l linux-image-* | awk '/ii/{print $2}'
```

Pick one, that is not your current kernel and delete corresponding files from boot:

```
sudo rm /boot/*-OLD_KERNEL_IMAGE_VERSION-*
```

Example:

```
sudo rm /boot/*-5.4.0-31-*
```

Fix "partial install":

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Let's do some cleanup:

```
sudo apt autoremove ; sudo apt clean
```

Update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's the difference with @A.G.Russell answer? Beyond the fact that he is doing a backup and you update the grub, Is it any reason to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend making a snapshot before doing this

I did:

```
uname -a
```

To get the used kernel version

```
ls -l /boot
```

To see all the versions

```
rm *4.4.0-(old unused versions)*
```

Then ran

```
sudo apt -f install
```

But then got a message: `W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.` and immediately noticed the /boot filling up again until 100% resulting in the apt erroring out.

But then found this: https://serverfault.com/a/623704

Noticed a similar discrepancy in my configs and ran

```
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
update-initramfs
```

Rebooted and then re-ran `sudo apt -f install` successfully

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find this thread when searching, so I started one: [How to rescue after apt install or upgrade fills disk space and breaks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392266/how-to-rescue-after-apt-install-or-upgrade-fills-disk-space-and-breaks), but its a duplicate.

Basically: use `apt clean` to get some disk space. Then Apt will work again. Then use `apt purge <package>`. You can find the last installed broken packages using `cat /var/log/apt/history.log`.

It would be great if Apt would say to "use apt clean if the disk is full", which it could check. It could also check for enough free space *before allowing* non-forced install.

This post suggests using `apt clean` and `apt install -f` to repair the database. I'm not sure apt clean work with apt broken and apt purge showing `apt --fix-broken install`. `apt install -f` seems to retry with force the pending install.
[Disk space issue after apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629238/disk-space-issue-after-apt-get-update)

Check out my other post for other tips on clearing disk space and also how to prevent it from filling up.