# Not enough free disk space for software update

Tags: boot, partitioning

*The upgrade needs a total of 97.6 M free space on disk'/
boot'. Please free at least an additional 62.1 M of disk
space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary
packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get
clean'.*

16.04 LTS installation on a 150G HDD
This was a fresh install, /dev/sda1  'boot' was assigned 240972 blocks at the time of the installation. i.e. sudo apt-get clean didn't have anything to remove.

I have a 150 GB HDD in my PC. This is a desktop installation.

How do I fix the problem??

Comment: Probably this is impossible until and unless you have some free space lying adjacent to the `/boot` partition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove old kernels/install new ones when /boot is full?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263363/how-can-i-remove-old-kernels-install-new-ones-when-boot-is-full)

Comment: @Amias `sudo apt-get autoremove` did the trick for me, so your suggestion is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permission error. It is probably caused because the program you are installing doesn't have the correct permissions to install in its location and interprets this as there not being enough disk space.

To solve this, first try starting Ubuntu in recovery (safe) mode. To do this restart your computer and while Ubuntu is booting, hold the left shift key (or if that doesn't work press 'esc' repetitively). This should open a GRUB boot menu. Using the arrow keys, select recovery mode and press enter. Wait for Ubuntu to boot, login to your account and retry the installation now.

If that doesn't work, try logging in as root and doing the installation, both with recovery mode and without recovery mode.