# Update to 16.10 (do-release-upgrade) fails due to not enough free disk space

Tags: apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

When doing a release upgrade I get the error:

> The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 1,279 M free space on disk '/'.

I used to solve this problem by moving the /var/cache/apt directory to my home partition (which has plenty of space), and then making a symlink to it:

```
sudo mv /var/cache/apt ~/.
sudo ln -s ~/apt /var/cache/apt
```

This worked up till 16.04.
It appears to no longer work in 16.10.

Does anybody know a way to get around this disk space issue without installing from a USB key or uninstalling packages?

Comment: Note that his is NOT a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading or http://askubuntu.com/questions/822973/not-enough-free-disk-space-for-software-update, etc. since those posts talk about free space in '/boot' and not '/'.

Comment: `/etc/apt` is not such big folder to help here

Comment: @Anwar: sorry, I fixed the typo.

Comment: You problem is that your disk partition for Ubuntu is way too small, and you're running out of space. Edit your question to include a screenshot of gparted, and I'll see if there's a fix by repartitioning your disk. Cheers, Al

Comment: I don't need a bigger partition since I have all the packages I need and there is still 1G of leeway.  What I'm looking for is a workaround for the problem of updating the system.  I realize that this wouldn't be a problem if I had a bigger '/' partition but my disk is small!

Comment: Obviously 1G leeway isn't enough, so you'll either have to delete stuff, or repartition. Did you clean up old kernels as @Anwar suggested? And still, if you upload that screenshot that I asked for, maybe I can help further. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 2):

**Update after OPs comment**

If moving `/var/cache/apt` to home doesn't help, check that your home partition has enough space. You can also try removing the extra icon themes you installed. A few icon themes can easily eat upto 1GB+ space these days.

Another option is removing older kernels you're not using. Use this question as a help [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

---

`/etc/apt` is not too big a folder to gain you significant improvement on the disk size. On the other hand, You can try moving the `/var/cache/apt` folder instead to your home and symlinking it, because that one is used to download all those .deb files.

Using your same commands before, you can do this

```
sudo mv /var/cache/apt ~/.
sudo ln -s ~/apt /var/cache/apt
```

Of course, You need to remove the folder `/var/cache/apt` first after `mv`-ing.

Comment: I'm sorry!  It was a typo.  I meant '/var/cache/apt'.

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin I've added a few more suggestions. what's your `/` partition size?

Comment: /dev/sda5        17G   15G  990M  94% /
/dev/sda7       367G  289G   59G  84% /home

Comment: oh. 17G is too low for `/`. Use `baobab` to check which files/directories are much space.

Comment: I'm really just curious in getting a workaround for not having a giant '/' directory.   I had a workaround that no longer works :(.

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin Have you done what I wrote in the answer? icon themes and older kernels?

Comment: I've installed the new system by removing some kruft packages etc.  But AGAIN:  this question is about how to trick the update manager into knowing I have enough space (since I've moved /var/cache/apt to my home directory)!

Comment: I tried mounting an extra disk at `/var/cache/apt`. Before and after, the upgrade tool complained about lack of disk space, but after mounting the extra disk, the amount of missing space had decreased from 3-ish to 2-ish G (trying to upgrade 18.04 to 20.04). Looks like `/var/cache/apt` isn’t the only folder involved, but I have no clue as to whether the extra space outside of it is even temporary at all, and where the extra files get stored.