# After I installed Ubuntu 22.04 "error processing package mdadm (--configure)"

Tags: raid, mdadm

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04LTS from 20.04LTS.

Now it appears that the "mdadm" package is giving me hassles.
Whenever I want to look for upgrades in terminal I get this error message:

```
Setting up mdadm (4.2-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
 installed mdadm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 20
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: This is a generic error message, a summary of what went wrong. Please do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (which tells the package manager to configure all unconfigured packages) and look for more specific error messages. The issue may also already be solved by this command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a post-installation script for a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389332/what-is-a-post-installation-script-for-a-package). This is the best response that can be given based on the scant information you have provided.