# apt cannot find header files: linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-060500-generic

Tags: apt, kernel, intel, 23.04

When I run anything with `apt`, it tells me to install missing header files. For example, running `sudo apt updgrade` produces:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-060500-generic (6.5.0-060500.202308271831) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-060500-generic (6.5.0-060500.202308271831) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-060500-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.5.0-060500-generic cannot be found at /lib/modules/6.5.0-060500-generic/build or /lib/modules/6.5.0-060500-generic/source.
Please install the linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.5.0-060500-generic cannot be found at /lib/modules/6.5.0-060500-generic/build or /lib/modules/6.5.0-060500-generic/source.
Please install the linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-060500-generic/x86_64 failed for evdi(1) virtualbox(1)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-060500-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-060500-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-060500-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-060500-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think I may have partially installed an unsuitable kernel, when trying to force the machine to upgrade to linux kernel 6.5.6.

machine spec:

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64 
Host: HP EliteBook 850 G8 Notebook PC 
Kernel: 6.2.0-1014-lowlatency 
Uptime: 8 mins 
Packages: 4942 (dpkg), 9 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 44.3 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1185G7 (8) @ 4.800GHz 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 
Memory: 2959MiB / 31771MiB
```

If I try to run `sudo apt autoremove` it encounters erroers processing `linux-image-unsigned-6.5.5-060505-generic`:

```
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.6-060506-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-6.5.6-060506-generic (--conf
igure):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-6.5.6-060506-generic package post-installation s
cript subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-6.5.5-060505-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-060500-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-6.5.6-060506-generic
```

Comment: Refer to: https://askubuntu.com/q/1389332/1460940

Comment: Please search for how to remove a Module from dkms trees complete