# dpkg error after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, dpkg

- **I'm encountering an issue when trying to remove a specific Linux kernel package on my Ubuntu system. The error seems to be related to a post-removal script that updates the GRUB bootloader configuration. Here are the details of the problem:**
- **I attempted to remove the package linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic using sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic.**
- But not fix the issue how can I fix this error please help Me.

```
/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic
```

Comment: Did you use Grub Customizer?

Comment: yes, I use Grub Customizer. Please suggest me how can I fix this error.

Comment: Have a look at [What is a post-installation script for a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389332/what-is-a-post-installation-script-for-a-package) It should provide some insights.

Comment: `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found` means something is broken in your grub customizer setup.  This is likely the base cause of your issue. I would suggest completely removing grub customizer if you can - after taking a clone or other backup of your system.

Answer (score 3):

I recently found solution at some github issue.

Try to replace /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux about 400 line (linux=...) to

`` linux=`echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -V | head -1 | cat` ``

Answer (score 1):

Ganesh, my grub was corrupted by the Customizer as well. I couldn't reinstall grub because of that error and nothing I found online worked.
I was desperate so I modified the script to skip that part and it installed grub which is working now.

No guarantees...
So, what I did was edited the 'linux' script mentioned in the error.
Searched for 'version_find_latest' and modified the while loop to skip it.
(I changed '!=x' to '=x')
Ran my 'apt upgrade' successfully then undid my change.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar error:

```
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found
```

And solved it with:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/grub.d/10_linux /tmp
$ sudo grub-mkconfig
```

Maybe a similar solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had needed to use the original `10_linux` which was next to my `10_linux` as `10_linux.dpkg-dist`.

Thus

```bash
cd /etc/grub.d
sudo mv 10_linux <Some backup path>
sudo mv 10_linux.dpkg-dist 10_linux
sudo update-grub
```

fixed the issue. Make sure that `update-grub` outputs something like

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
```

Otherwise you'll need to fix your system booting from a live system.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by Grub-Customizer. You can solve it uninstalling grub-customizer and deleting /etc/grub.d/LS_linux . Then you must run `sudo update-grub2`