I'd like to know how to debug my Ubuntu boot sequence since some of my later GRUB boot options will not boot, they just hang, "for ever"
Some ubuntu linux kernels don't boot while others do. Would like to find out why and hence get information on how to debug, if possible.
When I boot my Ubuntu some GRUB entries will not boot, e.g.:
"Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-1003-intel-opt",
"Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-27-generic",
"Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-26-generic"  while
"Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.1-060201-generic" do boot.
E.g 'Loading Linux 6.5.0-26-generic ...' and 'Loading initial ramdisk ...' shows on the screen but 6.5.0-* boot options only show two lines starting with "EFI...." after that and then hangs while the "6.2.1-x" option continues to boot fully. I have always used the Ubuntu Program Updater when loading new updates and upgrades. For those boots that fails I can't find Journal logs to debug. I have run the following command after booted using "6.2.1-x":
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/raw/main/system-info &&
  chmod +x system-info && ./system-info

and hence I can supply the output of this command if this might help me to get information on how to proceed debugging.

The system-info report documents your hardware & shows some boot info. But Boot-Repair's summary report shows all boot info and only some hardware info. Suggest running both and just post in question above the links to pastebin site. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

I have run programs for Boot-Repair and System-Info. Output can be found as:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SzncjT6bdk/    and
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wYHBTFrSFN/   respectively.

Not expert on system-info, but it looks normal. Boot-Repair report seemed to output a lot more info than usual, listed extra files. Line 252, shows several grub proxy files which are from Grub Customizer. It replaces grub with its own versions. Some have caused issues and difficult to fully remove. I would suggest removing Customizer, deleting/backup  /etc/grub.d and total reinstall of grub. Be sure to have good backups of everything. You will not be able to boot until grub re-installed. Can you boot recovery mode on other kernels? To command line?

Why not to use Grub Customizer
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/faq-why-you-should-not-use-grub-customizer/37844 &
https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/grub-customizer.html &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404445/grub-customizer-missing-from-ubuntu-22-04 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491726/dpkg-error-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-23-10 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491892/i-messed-up-my-grub-config

oldfred - Thanks for your advises. I was not able to boot any 6.5.* kernels using recovery mode. I have now removed Grub-Customizer using:
sudo apt purge grub-customizer
and prior to this copied /etc/grub.d/backup/* to a safe place.
then:
sudo apt remove grub grub2 grub-common .....
sudo apt install grub
and then copied files from the "backup" to appropriate dirs in the new grub installation. I have also run:
sudo update-grub

This though resulted in some info of "syntax errors in grub-files, so I run Boot-Repair.
After this, installation of grub went well and I felt satisfied and rebooted my laptop which directly started my Windows 10 installation.
Hence, I read somewhere how to configure Windows to boot and show boot alternatives before continue booting. After yet some restarts the only alternative to choose is Windows. :-(
Any advice on how to proceed?

If you installed package grub, that is incorrect as the 15 year old version. Grub2 packages are grub-pc for old BIOS systems or grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI systems in last 10 years or so. Best to post new report from Boot-Repair. Be sure to boot in correct boot mode, most systems are now UEFI.

Actually I've installed and now use grub2, as I understad it. Grub version is 2.12 (grub2 right?). To my understading Grub is 1.0 or less!!?? I've used efi in my working installation earlier. But now when I reboot I get only 1 boot option from grub2 - the Windows one.

Boot-Repair has has advance option to totally reinstall grub & kernel. Sometimes that fixes missing entry. Or you may need fsck on your Linux partition.

OK! Thanks! I will look into Boot-Repair again and see.
I am able to boot from a Ubuntu installation USB stick and so I have done and from there also tried to fix grub2 and EFI, but still I only get option to boot Windows. I am able to see the Ubuntu disk partition (/dev/sda5) and also EFI partition (/dev/sda1) from my earlier working installation and a number of linux kernels (6.5* and 6.2*).
But, as said, I will keep on trying to save my earlier installation.
Thanks a lot for your support.
