# Unmet dependencies when I tried to free up unused kernels

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

I am running 12.04.

I read this https://askubuntu.com/a/90219/18876 as reference.

I checked all the one I have.

```
yeukhon@fubini:~$ aptitude search ~ilinux-image
i   linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
i   linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic-pae     - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit 
BB  linux-image-generic-pae              - Generic Linux kernel image
```

I think I am using 39?

```
yeukhon@fubini:~$ uname -a
Linux fubini 3.2.0-39-generic-pae #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 27 22:25:11 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

So I started purging as suggested in the reference.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-29 linux-image-3.2.0-30 linux-image-3.2.0-31 linux-image-3.2.0-32 linux-image-3.2.0-33 linux-image-3.2.0-34 linux-image-3.2.0-35 linux-image-3.2.0-36 linux-image-3.2.0-37 linux-image-3.2.0-38
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-29'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-29-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-29'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-29-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-29'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-29'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-29-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-29'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-29-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-29'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-29-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-29'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-30-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-30'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-30-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-30'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-30-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-30'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-30-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-30'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-30'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-30'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-30-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-30'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-31'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-31'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-31-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-31'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-31-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-31'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-31-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-31'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-31-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-31'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-31-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-31'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-32'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-32'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-32'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-32'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-32'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-32'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-32'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-lowlatency-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-lowlatency' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-33-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-33'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-34'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-34-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-34'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-34-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-34'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-34'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-34-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-34'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-34-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-34'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-34-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-34'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-lowlatency-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-lowlatency' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-35-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-35'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-lowlatency' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-lowlatency-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-36'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-lowlatency' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-lowlatency-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-37'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-highbank' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-lowlatency' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-virtual' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-lowlatency-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-omap' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-powerpc64-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-powerpc-smp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-38'
Package linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-29-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic-pae is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-30-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-31-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-32-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-33-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-34-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-35-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-37-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-38-virtual is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-33-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-33-lowlatency-pae is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-35-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-35-lowlatency-pae is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-lowlatency-pae is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-37-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-37-lowlatency-pae is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-38-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.2.0-38-lowlatency-pae is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic-pae but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Now I don't know how to proceed, especially I don't want to mess up the computer.
Ideas? Thanks.

---

**Solution**

I found [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to) later. Basically, I followed his advise by `[removing] old vmlinuz initrd, abi and System.map files individually` until I got enough free space. I only need to delete the first two.

Then I do `sudo apt-get install -f` and finally use @Salem's little bash script to remove most of the old kernels. I kept the last two as suggested. Reboot at the end, and then if I do `uname -a` I will see the new kernel is now installed (in my case, that's 40).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that apt is trying to install/remove `linux-image-generic-pae`, which should point to the latest kernel available (which is `linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic-pae`) but the latest kernel you have installed is the `*39`.

So I suggest you to run the command suggested by apt with `--dry-run` (this will only simulate what apt would do):

```
sudo apt-get -f install --dry-run
```

This will let you know what apt is trying to do, and then you can decide if it is ok or not (if it tries to install the newest kernel that's ok, if it tries to remove the one you are using it may be better to try something else).

After that, probably the better way is to remove each kernel manually (in your `apt-get purge` output it seems to be selecting everyting correctly). You can specify each command alone or you can do something like:

```
for version in {29..38}; do
echo "Removing kernel 3.2.0-$version"
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.2.0-$version-generic-pae
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough disk space. I can't install the latest `40` as a result.

Comment: Check if `sudo apt-get clean` gets you some space.

Comment: Thanks! But still complain no space left. `failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during` `./boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic-pae': No space left on device``

Comment: Well if it doesn't let you remove any of the older kernels then you will need to free some space somewhere: try "Disk Usage analyzer" to see where space is being occupied. Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I managed to find this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to  I basically individually deleted about two old kernels. I am trying now.

Comment: Thanks. I just reboot. See my edit above.  Thanks a lot.