# Can't install updates due to boot folder size on 13.04

Tags: boot, disk, file-size

Update attempt delivers message 'Not enough free disk space' with the recommendation to free up space on /boot. I have tried all the clean up techniques I know, but essentially it is filled with all necessary stuff. What I can't understand is why the /boot volume is limited to only 40mb when there is 800gb free on my hard drive? What should I do about this? Thanks!

I have only Ubuntu installed, but the machine came with Win 8.

Comment: Please check http://askubuntu.com/a/90219/147253 and http://askubuntu.com/a/171225/147253

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Note: This solution involves moving /boot into to the linux root drive (/). It also involve grub-update, hence it is recommended to have a live CD/USB with you.

This is one way to forget about this issue, as all the contents will be moved to the root drive, which will have a much larger size.

1. Create a new copy of all the contents in /boot with the same permissions

> $ cp -pr /boot /boottemp

Unmount the /boot partition

> $ umount /boot

Comment (add a # in the beginning) the entry corresponding to the */boot*  partition  in file */etc/fstab*

Remove the /boot folder

> $ rmdir /boot

Make the /boottemp folder the new boot folder

> $ mv /boottemp /boot

Run grub update

> $ sudo update-grub

Reboot the system

> $ sudo reboot