# Clean up /boot directory

Tags: boot, grub2, cleanup

After an update of my Ubuntu I came to the error, "I cannot update since /boot is full".
The thing is, that when I compared the results of the two following commands
`$dpkg --list 'linux-image*'`, `$uname -r` I noticed that I use an older kernel. In my case the second command gave 3.13.0-24-generic and the first gave many newer version kernels e.g. linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic. The question is 1.why Grub does not update to a new kernel version? 2.I am not sure which kernel versions to delete in order to free some space in /boot. The question here [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209) answers how to free some space  but not why my Grub does not use the newer kernel vesrions.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using at this point?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: possible duplicate of [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try following the readme at:  https://github.com/erichs/bootnukem

```
git clone https://github.com/erichs/bootnukem.git
cd bootnukem
sudo ./install.sh
```

Then

```
./bootnukem --dry-run
```