# How do I remove old kernels despite 100% inode use in /usr?

Tags: kernel, inode

I was trying to update my packages today:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-3.16.0-44-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.16.0-44 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So, I went ahead and tried `apt-get -f install`:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-44
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-44
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,101 kB of archives.
After this operation, 64.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 688666 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-44_3.16.0-44.59_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-44 (3.16.0-44.59) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.16.0-44_3.16.0-44.59_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-44/scripts/genksyms/Makefile.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-44/scripts/genksyms/Makefile'): No space left on device
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.16.0-44_3.16.0-44.59_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It's complaining saying `No space left on device`. `df -Th` tells me that there's sufficient space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       3.3G  2.5G  571M  82% /
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M   11M  384M   3% /run
tmpfs           2.0G   28M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M   72K  100M   1% /run/user
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda7       9.3G  7.6G  1.3G  87% /usr
/dev/sda8       188G  176G  3.0G  99% /home
/dev/sda1       945M  394M  487M  45% /boot
/dev/sda9       256G  9.6G  233G   4% /var
```

However, `df -i` tells me `/usr` has used up all the inodes.

These are the dirs and their inode usage:

```
/usr/bin = 2846
/usr/etc = 1
/usr/games = 8
/usr/include = 3204
/usr/lib = 42317
/usr/local = 105
/usr/lost+found = 1
/usr/sbin = 306
/usr/share = 228141
/usr/src = 348704
```

So, if I can clear out `/usr/src` (which contains the current and old kernels), I can probably resolve the issue. But, I keep running into the first error:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-3.16.0-44-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.16.0-44 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any suggestions on how I can remove my old kernels?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have /usr on a separate partition? Could you please post the output of `df -h`? The reason I ask is that most of the times your issue happens is when `/boot` is full. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to) for that.

Comment: @NZD, I have 487mb in /boot. I just added the output of `df -h` to my post. I don't think /boot is the issue.

Comment: There seems to be enough space on /usr. One way of freeing up inodes is to copy a number of directories to another partition (/var seems to have a lot GBs left), rename the copied directories on /usr, then create links on /usr to the copied directories on /var to restore your system. After that you can delete the renamed directories from /usr. I've done that before with /var and that worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was running out of options and time so I tried this and it worked:

I figured out what kernel I was using:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-44-generic
```

I decided to move the really old kernels to my external storage:

```
sudo mv linux-headers-3.8* /media/housni/linux-headers
```

`df -i` then showed that a significant amount of inodes have been freed so I quickly uninstalled the headers I knew I wouldn't need:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.8*
```

After which, I updated grub and rebooted

```
sudo update-grub2 && sudo shutdown now -r
```

I then did some extra clean up like cleaning up my cache (`sudo apt-get clean`) and running autoremove (`sudo apt-get autoremove`) just to be safe and now everything seems to be back to normal :)

Comment: Any alternate way than external storage? Got a server image that is full - no physical access. Would it be possible to manually delete the oldest image to free up some inodes?

Comment: If they are not in use, you can delete them. Delete as few as possible, fix the issue and then clean out the rest. Maybe move it to /var/ or /tmp where you probably have a bit of free space.