# Can't install new software/packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I was having an issue with updating packages and I was getting 404's to au.archive.ubuntu.com.

I seem to have resolved now however I am now getting this;

```
llibke@libke:~$ sudo apt-get -f install smartmontools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acl at-spi2-core colord dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service enchant
  fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gedit-common gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnome-user-guide gsettings-desktop-schemas
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x
  hicolor-icon-theme hunspell-en-us libaa1 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0
  libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libavc1394-0 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2
  libcairo2 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra0
  libcdparanoia0 libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libdatrie1 libdconf1 libdee-1.0-4
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdv4 libenchant1c2a libexif12
  libflac8 libfontconfig1 libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
  libgeoclue0 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa
  libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port10 libgraphite2-3
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
  libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2
  libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libhunspell-1.3-0 libice6 libicu52
  libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3 libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper1
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common liblcms2-2 libllvm3.4 libnotify4
  libogg0 liborc-0.4-0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libpixman-1-0
  libproxy1 libpython3.4 libraw1394-11 libsane libsane-common libsecret-1-0
  libsecret-common libshout3 libsm6 libsoup2.4-1 libspeex1 libtag1-vanilla
  libtag1c2a libtelepathy-glib0 libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libtiff5
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvisual-0.4-0
  libvisual-0.4-plugins libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvpx1
  libwavpack1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwebp5 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0
  libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1
  libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6
  libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1
  libxslt1.1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86vm1 libyelp0 libzeitgeist-2.0-0
  linux-headers-3.13.0-45 linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-46 linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-48 linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-49 linux-headers-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-51 linux-headers-3.13.0-51-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-52 linux-headers-3.13.0-52-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-53 linux-headers-3.13.0-53-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-54 linux-headers-3.13.0-54-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-55 linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-57 linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-58 linux-headers-3.13.0-58-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-59 linux-headers-3.13.0-59-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-61 linux-headers-3.13.0-61-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-62 linux-headers-3.13.0-62-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-65 linux-headers-3.13.0-65-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-66 linux-headers-3.13.0-66-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic
  notification-daemon python-cairo python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-gi
  python-gi-cairo python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-zeitgeist
  sound-theme-freedesktop x11-common yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core
  zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  heirloom-mailx
Suggested packages:
  gsmartcontrol smart-notifier
Recommended packages:
  mailx mailutils
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  heirloom-mailx smartmontools
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 1 to remove and 272 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/664 kB of archives.
After this operation, 150 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 579763 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic (3.13.0-76.120) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-76-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-76-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-76-generic: No such file or directory
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_nzqd2J/lib/modules/3.13.0-76-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_nzqd2J/lib/modules/3.13.0-76-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-76-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to no avail.
I'm only really just starting to learn Linux, and I'm a bit lost here and help would be appreciated.

End goal, actually be able to install new packages such as smartmontools.

Part 2:

```
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic        3.13.0-45.74                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic        3.13.0-46.79                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic        3.13.0-48.80                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic        3.13.0-49.83                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic        3.13.0-51.84                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic        3.13.0-52.86                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic        3.13.0-53.89                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic        3.13.0-54.91                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic        3.13.0-55.94                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic        3.13.0-57.95                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic        3.13.0-58.97                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic        3.13.0-59.98                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic        3.13.0-61.100                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic        3.13.0-62.102                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic        3.13.0-63.103                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic  3.13.0-45.74                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic  3.13.0-46.79                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic  3.13.0-48.80                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic  3.13.0-49.83                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic  3.13.0-51.84                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic  3.13.0-52.86                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic  3.13.0-53.89                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic  3.13.0-54.91                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic  3.13.0-55.94                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic  3.13.0-57.95                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic  3.13.0-58.97                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic  3.13.0-59.98                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic  3.13.0-61.100                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic  3.13.0-62.102                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic  3.13.0-63.103                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic  3.13.0-65.105                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic  3.13.0-66.108                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic  3.13.0-76.120                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Part 3

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic        3.13.0-63.103                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic  3.13.0-45.74                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic  3.13.0-46.79                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic  3.13.0-48.80                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic  3.13.0-49.83                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic  3.13.0-51.84                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic  3.13.0-52.86                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic  3.13.0-53.89                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic  3.13.0-54.91                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic  3.13.0-55.94                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic  3.13.0-57.95                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic  3.13.0-58.97                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic  3.13.0-59.98                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic  3.13.0-61.100                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic  3.13.0-62.102                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic  3.13.0-63.103                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic  3.13.0-65.105                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic  3.13.0-66.108                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic  3.13.0-76.120                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: The `gzip: stdout: No space left on device message makes me suspect you're out of space on your /boot partition (though there could be other issues as well). Can someone give directions on how to free up some space there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are lots of unused packages and dependencies junked in your system and also old linux images and headers. So first try

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I think this will solve your problem for now.

***UPDATE***

I was bit of a hurry when I post the last answer and happy to see that helped you but seeing your last post output I don't think that freed up `/boot` partition completely because there were lots of old kernels occupying at least a gig of space and `autoremove` will not clean them. So enter in your terminal

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

and look for the entries like `linux-image-x.xx.x-xx-generic` and if there is more than one entry then purge the old ones one by one keeping the latest one as follows...

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.xx.x-xx-generic
```

DO IT CAREFULLY AND DON'T REMOVE THE LATEST KERNEL.

Comment: Hello Kiran, Thank you again, I have done this and above the list under "Part 2" of my main post is the list, I have removed all except linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic. Should I also be removing the linux-image-extra-X.XX.X-XX-generic?

Comment: No, after purging all other kernels there should be one kernel image, one image extra package and one header package left out. Post output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`.

Comment: Sorry i've been a bit busy today. "Part 3" is the current output of:   'dpkg --list | grep linux-image'

Comment: Ok!! Sorry for the late reply!! Yes, you can remove them similar way one by one keeping the matching kernel version number! By the way, is it a virtual machine install??