# Cannot Upgrade (No space left on device + Unmet dependencies)

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

I run a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04 (hosted at 1&1). The problem I encounter is when trying to upgrade:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Here is what it returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I thus try:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Which returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-59
  linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62
  linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-63
  linux-headers-4.4.0-63-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-67
  linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 66.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 406956 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic (4.4.0-72.93) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I try to autoremove the packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

And only get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried removing individual packages:

```
apt-get remove linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So, my /boot partition is full and I cannot find get a way to make some space.

```
/dev/sda1              464M  456M     0 100% /boot
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT:

`df -i` gives:

```
Filesystem             Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                   121341    451  120890    1% /dev
tmpfs                  125929    611  125318    1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01 3121152 446547 2674605   15% /
tmpfs                  125929      1  125928    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  125929      3  125926    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                  125929     16  125913    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1              124928    346  124582    1% /boot
tmpfs                  125929      4  125925    1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: what is the output of `df -i `

Comment: You are trying to remove old kernels and the system wants to install a new one to replace them, how about removing some of the older kernels one by one before attempting to install the new one. The system needs a kernel to boot from and an older one for fall back in case of an error or attempting to restore the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh I edited the question with the output. @MuaadElSharif I tried `sudo apt autoremove` as well as to remove individual package like `apt-get remove linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic` but it says they have unmet dependencies. How do you suggest to do it?

Comment: @muru Thanks, I solved it by manually removing the old Kernels, like suggested in the upvoted answer by John S Gruber.