# How to free space on a full /boot partition?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel, dpkg, boot-partition

Stuck running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Lenova desktop with a small boot partition now with 0(zero) bytes after many upgrades. Currently at 4.4.0-71-generic but new upgrades fail. Have tried suggestions from many "solutions" but still can not upgrade.

None of the following free-up space:

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt autoremove --purge

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

sudo purge-old-kernels

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-67
```

Have also purged all the other old linux-images that do not have dependencies.

Any new suggestions?

Comment: Also examine [https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

Comment: With the sheer size of todays hard drives I don't understand why people insist on making /boot as small as possible. If you do you need to keep as few kernels as possible, I suggest no more then 3