# Error when running sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, sudo

```
jan@XXXXX:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

so I run apt-get -f install

```
jan@XXXXX:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70
  linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75
  linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87
  linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 95 not to upgrade.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/43.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 134 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 451167 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic (4.4.0-92.115) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-92-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-92-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic_4.4.0-87.110_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic (4.4.0-87.110) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic_4.4.0-87.110_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-87-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-87-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic_4.4.0-87.110_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And it just won't update itself...

Any help would be welcome...

Thanks

Comment: Did you start by running `sudo apt-get update` to update repository database first ?

Comment: yes, of course I did...

Comment: i even try to delete repository database and rebuild it with no luck...

Comment: anyway, I believe that the answer below is actually correct

Answer (score 0):

I can see "failed to write (No space left on device) No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error" in the error output, so you probably need to free up some disk space first.

Comment: Ok when I run   jan@XXXXX:~$ df 
/dev/sda1                       482922   474149          0 100% /boot So it looks like you are correct and sda1 is full... any easy way to fix this?

Comment: note i am familiar with partitions etc... but never needed to deal with it on linux... can it be done directly from command line(from server itself)?

Comment: @JanZoudlik it should be possible. Your question has been marked as a duplicate of another (https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to) and that other question has a few helpful looking suggestions.