# I'm upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. Which of these files are the most important to backup?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, backup

[image]

I know most of the information I use in my daily basis is stored in the home folder, however, I want to be sure nothing important is left out of the backup.

Edit: Which command I use to copy these files into an external HD?

Comment: Your question's body and title don't match completely. What are you looking for exactly? Command to copy files or which files to backup? Also what "most important" to you is up to you, others can't possibly answer it unless you explain which type of files you're looking to backup. Please **[edit]** your question and clarify your issue.

Comment: Since the answer to the other question solved your problem, I am voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are "important files"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955935/what-are-important-files) (in case you prefer to back up less than your entire system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only files that are important for you to backup are the **user data in de home folders of the different users of the system**. All the other folders contain system files.

Do not put efforts in backing up these. Operating systems come for free and are installed in less than 30 minutes. Personal user data, however, is unique and can be lost forever if not good backup exists.

Answer (score 1):

I have ubuntu and upgrade just fine just make sure all programs are closed and your good, but if you really want to back it up just go into files and copy and paste them to the external hard drive.

Comment: Hi nochintator, I want to know which files I have to backup, any idea?

Comment: root is YOUR files the others are system files they will need updating with ubuntu so leave them there

Comment: why don't you back them all up do you not have enough space on the drive?

Answer (score 1):

I already made a backup following the instructions on this post: [backup - How to back up my entire system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system). This link also leads to another forum where you can find the complete information: [Howto: Backup and restore your system! by Heliode](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087)

If you were searching the same thing as I did some days ago, I recommend you to follow the instructions on the links
above.