# Circular dependency on apt-get upgrade (not package dependency)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dependencies

I have unmet dependencies so my upgrade command fails with:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-80-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-80-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-vivid : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-80-generic but it is not going to be installed
                                 Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
```

the problem is that I have full boot partition so apt-get -f install fails.

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-80-generic (3.19.0-80.88~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-80-generic_3.19.0-80.88~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-80-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-80-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
```

I tried to remove unused kernels with

```
 apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
```

but it fails with original error - unmet dependencies.

So I have circular dependency in issues with upgrade. What is the safest way to resolve it? Is it safe to manually delete kernels from /boot?

Comment: You're using an old, unsupported Ubuntu release. There's no point in troubleshooting this. Please install and use a supported release at all times.

Comment: It is not a circular dependency , the problem is your  boot is full https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to