# GoAccess installation fails on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS due to linux-image package

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to install GoAccess (https://goaccess.io) on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, I was following this tutorial - https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-goaccess-on-ubuntu-16-04

So when I entered following command -

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

it throws me following errors -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic but it is not installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then I tried the following command -

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But it ends with an error which is -

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic_4.4.0-75.96_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I thought to install the dependencies seprately, and executed following command -

```
sudo apt-get -f install linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
```

but this command ended up with following error -

```
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic (4.4.0-75.96) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic_4.4.0-75.96_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-75-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-75-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic_4.4.0-75.96_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody help me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer, it was lack of space in boot. This is the answer that worked for me - https://askubuntu.com/a/171225/742040