# How do I free up more space (increase partition size) in /boot on a VPS?

Tags: boot, partitioning, webmin

My boot partition is full. I cannot apply system updates. How can I resize partitions? I don't want to remove old files, I only want to resize. I can not install gparted because I do not have desktop access. Is it possible to do it from webmin ?

I tried these methods:

[My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

[How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

[How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

```
[root@mail ~]# sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gparted : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-133-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-133-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-133-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try `apt-get -f install` then I get "disk full" error.

Screenshots from webmin.

[image: partitions]

[image: logical volumes]

[image: physical volume]

[image: logical volumes]

[image: disk and network file system]

Comment: i want to edit partition size. previous topic is not work for my system.

Comment: gparted can not install. i did try all previos method.

Comment: its vps server. how can I boot vps server with dvd/usb  ?

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`?  (which will remove .debs that are no longer needed; where its hoped it'll include old kernels)

Comment: `[root@mail ~]# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-133-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-133-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-133-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

Comment: Classic XY problem. You resize a VPS using the VPS Provider's tools, since you cannot boot from a LiveUSB. Fair warning: Resizing the LVM partition may destroy all your data - they are not meant to be resized. You avoid all this trouble by running occasional maintenance (autoremove) on  your /boot.

Comment: after delete files from webmin file manager then `apt-get autoremove` worked. `apg-get -f install` worked. everything working good. thanx everyone. (my vps is very less tools. because its 1 euro/month only.so i can not edit or backup disks.)

Answer (score 0):

I did delete old kernel files from webmin file manager, so I have more space on boot. I did not try resize process yet.

[image: webmin file manager]

After deleting files from webmin file manager then `apt-get autoremove` worked. `apt-get -f install` worked. Everything is working good. Thanks everyone.