# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb (--unpack)

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

I know that this is a common problem and i have tried many "fixes" but none of them worked.

I want to install an update to one of my programs, but i can't because it says that I have unmet dependencies. I used `sudo apt install -f` and I got `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` in detail:

```
Reading package lists... 0%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms gcc-5-base:i386 grub-efi-amd64-bin libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libllvm4.0
  libllvm5.0:i386 libqmi-glib1 libsensors4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
  libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-headers-4.4.0-101
  linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-108
  linux-headers-4.4.0-108-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-119 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87 linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-104-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-108-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-87-generic mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mokutil shim vdpau-driver-all:i386
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 177 not upgraded.
30 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/44.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 136 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 603843 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/abi-4.4.0-119-generic' to '/boot/abi-4.4.0-119-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic_4.4.0-127.153_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-127-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic (4.4.0-127.153) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic_4.4.0-127.153_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/abi-4.4.0-127-generic' to '/boot/abi-4.4.0-127-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-127-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-127-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic_4.4.0-127.153_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

So after that i run: dpkg -a --configure and got this: 

`subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-104-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-127-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-116-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-103-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic
 friendly-recovery
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-108-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic
 linux-firmware
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-109-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 initramfs-tools
```

I really don't know what to do, this isn't the first time this happened, the last time it happened i just reinstalled the entire OS, however now with my PLEX libary reaching well over 7 TB, that is out of the question. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) and [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

Comment: If you have really 'tried many "fixes" but none of them work,' then it is quite possible that you have made the problem worse or the solution more difficult.

Comment: The error you mentioned is unfortunately completely generic. The real error is the one telling you you have "No space on device" - too many old kernels in the boot partition (use `sudo apt autoremove` regularly to avoid this in future after resolving this issue).