# Boot partition full, cannot run software updater

Tags: boot, apt

[error that says not enough space on boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2iNd.png)

`sudo apt-get -f autoremove`

results in

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 100 not upgraded.`

I've manually removed all kernels (with `sudo rm` on /boot) except for `5.14.0-1033-oem` that I've got from `uname -a`. This solved lack of space problem for a little bit, so I could run autoremove, and fix-broken (previously they were failing due to lack of space on /boot). But those commands brought a lot of kernels back and there is no space on boot again.

My previous post [0 bytes left on /boot, apt autoremove and apt --fix-broken install fail due to unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410549/0-bytes-left-on-boot-apt-autoremove-and-apt-fix-broken-install-fail-due-to-u) was marked as answered in [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to) , but in fact I've done everything from the linked answers just to come back to original situation.

Comment: Ubuntu automatically removes and deletes superseded kernels to free up space in /boot, so something else is wrong with your system if that automatic mechanism is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the answer was for me to do the whole exercise again.

To sum up the whole story:

- first rm from boot every kernel related file, except for the one from `uname -a`
- `sudo apt autoremove` , `sudo apt --fix-broken install` , `sudo apt clean`
- now /boot is almost full again, because --fix-broken has put a lot of kernel files in /boot
- again remove every kernel but `uname -a`
- now I'm cool and I can run software updater without errors

This is a little bit counterintuitive but it worked.

Comment: You are describing brute-force methods that are not required. Instead, use `ls` to learn the kernels that are installed. Use `dpkg` to uninstall one of those extra kernel packages by name (it can do that, even if the partition is full).. Then use `apt` to uninstall the rest of the extra kernel packages by name (easier than using dpkg). Then `apt autoremove` and `apt autoclean` to tidy up. No need for `rm`. No need for `--fix-broken-install`.