# ubuntu disk size is getting full

Tags: 18.04, disk, disk-usage

I am running ubuntu 18.04lts with 15gb disk space but my disk is getting full I have Elasticsearch and tomcat installed on that disk.

I have tried many commands to clean the disk like

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=3d
```

but only managed to clean 1.1gb of data can anyone help or suggest me to any solution  to clean up atleast 4gb of the total disk size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be you can use [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) to find out what is taking up your space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: @karel nope this does not answer my question.

Comment: Your root partition is too small.

Comment: yes @karel I know that.

Comment: That's why you should resize it.