# "boot" volume in 12.10 , only 5mb left

Tags: 12.10, boot

one of my other ubuntu machines keeps on giving the message the my boot volume is almost full with 5.5 mb left. I see there is answers for ubuntu 10.04, but mine is 12.10. I've tried uninstalling software in ubuntu software center, but with no success, giving me a error in the uninstalling process, telling me that it can't be uninstalled. What do I do to rectify this? Please asssit me

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ubuntu!

One thing to realize is that your hard drive can be logically split up into smaller pieces. These pieces are called partitions. There are many advantages and disadvantages to partitioning, but that is a topic for [another time](http://www.pcworld.com/article/185941/how_and_why_to_partition_your_hard_drive.html). Just realize that this means that installing and removing apps will *not* affect the boot volume (most of the time).

Based on what you've said, you have your a separate partition which your computer uses to start up from called the "boot volume". You may have residual kernels and other files on there that are taking too much space. As long as you have a normal Ubuntu installation, these commands can be pretty safely run:

While booted into that computer, run this command:
`dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge`.

This will clear out the unused kernels and initrd's that you are not using.

(Adapted from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot) question that is similar)

Comment: worked great in xubuntu 12.10... Thanks!