# How can I increase partition sizes when adding a new drive on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Do the answers in [How can I add more disk space to /boot for update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377641/how-can-i-add-more-disk-space-to-boot-for-update/1506509#1506509) still work in the newest Ubuntu 22.04? Can I just order a new drive format it and resize boot to the right and be done? And does that work also for expanding home?

I have the same problem where nothing helps to free enough space and when I buy a new drive I would like to resize the rest of the space to home.

```
sudo lsblk -f


NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS

sda                                                                           
├─sda1
│    vfat   FAT32       2DBC-43FC                                   1G     1% /boot/efi
├─sda2
│    swap   1           09c54359-ba24-4a3e-9442-eb527496337a                  [SWAP]
├─sda3
│    ext4   1.0         8ea302c5-b2f3-46fb-a50a-a4f8377a8044         0    94% /boot
└─sda4
     LVM2_m LVM2        Lx2mUh-pbgT-qI88-xauW-bsfX-wPZ7-5cBAtO                
  └─vg0-lv--0
     xfs                343d781f-b8cd-4dc7-ace5-a642b30c4d9a      8.5T    22% /
```

Here is a screenshot of the output that looks might be more clear!:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSDW7.png

Comment: Your link seems to be more for housecleaning to make more space. I generally recommend new clean install, so you can choose sizes as desired & then restore from your standard updated backup.  Good test that backup is complete. You cannot have duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs, so cannot reboot with both drives connected if planning to keep using old drive. Also is system UEFI or BIOS, partitioned with gpt or very old MBR(msdos)? If you have /boot are you using full drive encryption? Otherwise /boot as partition generally not required. Post this `sudo lsblk -f` in question above.

Comment: I am not sure I used this guide to install ubuntu server!:    https://systemzone.net/ubuntu-server-20-04-installation-with-lvm/

Comment: I have a lot stuff that I dont want to loose like a cloud instance and other stuff over 1tb! I am not sure how backups work! I am generally new to ubuntu!

Comment: I do not use Clouds. You should have a backup drive larger than any data you want to keep whether Ubuntu or other operating system. If no backup, then you data must not be important. I do not like image backups, and use rsync for /home after exporting list of installed apps. If server you may have data in / folders that also need backup. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436006 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/320458/how-to-exclude-multiple-directories-with-rsync

Comment: Have you seen the output of?: sudo lsblk -f

Comment: I would if possible avoid backup stuff and recover is there a different way? On hand of the output of: sudo lsblk -f

Comment: Removed snaps (the loop mounts) & changed formatting, almost correct. Do not know LVM nor xfs.  Your /boot does seem rather full, not sure if related to xfs or not.  Those that know LVM may want these commands also: `sudo pvs` & 
sudo vgs` & 
`sudo lvs`  Since xfs, you cannot run fsck, and may need whatever is the equivalent in xfs.

Comment: Sorry it sounds very complex and i just understand a part I just choose a easy way I bought a nvme and copy all important files and delete the server drives and reinstall ubuntu that should fix my problem this time I will set boot to 50 or 100gb to avoid in the future such issues!

Comment: thanks for your help I learned some new stuff! :) Sorry for your wasted time!