# Can't install/remove packages - update-initramfs with little space on /boot

Tags: apt, partitioning, kernel

When I try to remove any package, I get

```
(Reading database ... 604878 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bootchart (0.90.2-8ubuntu2) ...
[skipped]
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-32-generic: No such file or directory
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package bootchart (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
```

`/boot` partition has 263 MB of space and I've removed some old kernel files with `rm -f /boot/*3.13.0-3*` to free space before. I don't think I've purged linux-kernel packages back then.

Either way now I can't even use the answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot) - when I try to `apt-get purge linux-image-3.11.0-20-generic` I still run into the issue with with initramfs.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with `bootchart` `/var/lib/dpkg/info/bootchart.postrm` script. I edited it to remove the `update-initramfs` command, and then I was able to remove bootchart and old `linux-image` packages normally, which freed up a lot of space in `/boot`.