# New software can't be installed because there is a problem with the software currently installed--trying to install Loggerpro for Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

When I try to install **loggerpro**, this is the message I get. I looked on the forum and tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall deconf
```

and then it says: `unable to access package deconf`
then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf
```

and then i got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-60-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

then I try apt-get install:

XXXXX:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What do I do now? I'm not a computer person, so if you can explain what I should do next in the simplest terms possible I would really appreciate it!

OKay, I tried what john Orion suggested and this is what i got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1 linux-headers-3.16.0-30
  linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-utopic-tools linux-headers-3.16.0-60-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 195 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/31.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 69.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 356758 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic_3.16.0-62.82~14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic (3.16.0-62.82~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic_3.16.0-62.82~14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-62-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-62-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-62-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-62-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic_3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic (3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic_3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-60-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-60-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I still can't install new software, and get the same error message, and the dependency not satisfiable: vstdrivers.

Any other ideas?????

Comment: You need to be using root permissions when you use apt-get .. try `sudo apt-get -f install` when it asks for a password ..use your users login password but be aware it  doesn't show any indication that a password is being typed.. just type it in and press enter

Comment: @JohnOrion You might want to convert that to an answer, it will most likely solve his problem.

Comment: `utopic`? I believe that you are a bit out-dated...

Comment: Hi, I tried what John Orion suggested and this is what I got:4

Answer (score 0):

From the errors such as `failed to write (No space left on device)`, it looks like the Ubuntu partition on your hard drive is full. Perhaps you could delete some files or transfer them to another drive or partition, and then re-visit this issue. You could also run `sudo apt-get clean` to free up some space.

**Update**: Since the errors are related to kernel installation, it's likely that you need to free up space in you `/boot` directory, which may be in a different partition than the rest of your system. Please see the answer to this question for instructions on how to do that: [Can't upgrade due to low disk space on /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot)

Comment: Hi I just tried that and nothing happens. just to be clear it's sudo apt-get clean     written just like that?

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-get clean` . If that doesn't help, then you need to free up space in other ways.

Comment: I've also deleted several films, music, etc, and I still get this message.

Comment: what should happend after I type in sudo apt-get clean   ? all that happens is I'm immediately brought back to my XXX@XXX:~$ It's almost as though it isn't processing the command?

Comment: If there are no errors, then it worked. However, I think the problem is actually with your `/boot` partition; please see the edit I just made to my answer.

Comment: Hi; thanks for all the help! I've tried to get rid of old kernels using the commands reccommended in the 'can't upgrade due to low disk space on /boot' and still get: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) Also, I realized (thru reading through some comments) that maybe I have low disk space because i'm using 14.04, encrypted. Is there a way to increase the disc space without unencrypting my computer? thanks so much for the help, but i still can't download loggerpro!!!