# Freeing up /boot space for upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, disk-usage

As in the topic i have to free some space at boot, but don't really know how. I'm pretty new to ubuntu, only understand few commands, and I found one solution to delete all unused kernels (I'm sure I have few since there are a lot of files in boot), but don't know how. I found the command to delete them but for different versions (?) and can't redo it by myself. Here is list of files in boot.

```
abi-4.2.0-34-generic         initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
abi-4.2.0-35-generic         lost+found
abi-4.2.0-36-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.2.0-38-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-4.2.0-41-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-4.2.0-42-generic         System.map-4.2.0-34-generic
config-4.2.0-34-generic      System.map-4.2.0-35-generic
config-4.2.0-35-generic      System.map-4.2.0-36-generic
config-4.2.0-36-generic      System.map-4.2.0-38-generic
config-4.2.0-38-generic      System.map-4.2.0-41-generic
config-4.2.0-41-generic      System.map-4.2.0-42-generic
config-4.2.0-42-generic      vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-36-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic
```

And here is the command i found:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-{3.0.0-12,2.6.3{1-21,2-25,8-{1[012],8}}}
```

Can anyone help me redo it for my files ? And maybe explain it a bit ?
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't upgrade due to low disk space on /boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot) and possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer, the command should look like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.2.0-{34,35,36,38}
```

And it worked like a charm :)