# How do you find out when a specific kernel version was last booted?

Tags: kernel, scripts, inode

## Find out when a Specific Kernel Version was last booted

For those who manually install kernel versions the `/boot` can grow large over time. I'd like find which kernel versions haven't been booted in a long time as candidates for removal.

## File last accessed time

To facilitate this project I would need to know when each kernel was last booted. I saw a Q&A for finding files older than a certain date using the `atime`. However this Q&A went searching for files older than x days. I'm looking for all files and wanting to know the last access time.

Via bash script how would one determine a given file's last access time?

## Edit 1 - Must set Kernel Version's last access time during boot

When grub mounts the kernel it is in `ro` (read-only) mode and the last access time is not updated.

If you run `update-initramfs -u -k all` the file `initrd.img` the last access time is updated for all kernels even though they haven't been booted today.

When installing a new kernel the all previous kernel version files `system.map-w.x.yy-zzz` last access time is updated even though they haven't been booted today.

To correctly record when a kernel version was REALLY booted we need to `touch` the file `vmlinuz-w.x.yy-zzz`. Using sudo powers create a file like this in `/etc/cron.d/`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot   root    touch "/boot/vmlinuz-"`uname -r`
```

Now when listing files in `/boot` using muru's answer:

**find /boot/vm* -printf "%Ac %p\n"**

```
Thu 21 Jul 2016 05:02:48 AM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Wed 26 Oct 2016 05:10:08 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-113-generic
Sat 15 Oct 2016 10:45:41 AM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-43-generic
Thu 20 Oct 2016 06:09:00 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Sat 06 Aug 2016 09:32:02 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.3-040603-generic
Sun 21 Aug 2016 12:59:04 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.1-040701-generic
Fri 26 Aug 2016 04:51:04 AM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.2-040702-generic
Thu 08 Sep 2016 06:46:52 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-040703-generic
Sun 25 Sep 2016 07:25:46 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.5-040705-generic
Sat 08 Oct 2016 03:08:45 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.1-040801-generic
Sat 22 Oct 2016 08:16:44 AM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.4-040804-generic
Sun 30 Oct 2016 12:56:12 PM MDT /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.5-040805-generic
```

## Check Free Space before installing new Kernel Version

Before installing a new kernel it's a good idea to check how much space is available in `/boot` and/or how much is already being used with these commands:

```
rick@dell:~$ df /boot
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc3       30106300 20449376   8104556  72% /
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ du /boot --max-depth 0 -h
565M    /boot
```

To see how much space will be saved by deleting a specific previous kernel use this command:

```
rick@dell:~$ du /boot/*4.8.1* -h
1.4M    /boot/abi-4.8.1-040801-generic
204K    /boot/config-4.8.1-040801-generic
44M /boot/initrd.img-4.8.1-040801-generic
3.6M    /boot/System.map-4.8.1-040801-generic
4.8M    /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.1-040801-generic
```

Comment: Add a bootup script to get the kernel version currently running, log it to a file, and use that file for access time data?

Comment: `echo "$(date) $(uname -srv)"  >> ~/.kernellog.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/stat.1) command:

```
   %x     time of last access, human-readable
   %X     time of last access, seconds since Epoch
```

So:

```
stat -c %X /some/file
```

Or with `find`:

```
find /some/path -printf "%A@ %p\n"
```

Since for `find`'s `-printf`:

```
  %a     File's  last  access time in the format returned by the C
         `ctime' function.

  %Ak    File's last access time in the  format  specified  by  k,
         which  is  either `@' or a directive for the C `strftime'
         function.  The possible values for k  are  listed  below;
         some  of  them might not be available on all systems, due
         to differences in `strftime' between systems.

         @      seconds  since  Jan.  1,  1970,  00:00  GMT,  with
                fractional part.
```

Comment: Haha who knew?... well obviously muru the guru! Thank you very much :)  Well except for the fact you're creeping up on me for points totals for week now :D Anyway just tried `stat -c %x /boot/vmlinuz-4*` and it works like a charm. However for programming I should use `Epoch` but what does that mean?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Epoch is the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). So you get a number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. It's easier to compare when you have a plain number without any date formatting.

Comment: definitely easier for programming. How can I find out today's Epoch? Or should I just click your link? (Interesting only 1.4 GB of seconds since 1970 who knew???)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix now would be `date +%s`

Comment: TYVM... I have my weekend project lined up now.

Comment: The `find` method in the answer generates a wall of text as each file from `printf` isn't separated by new line/carriage return.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix fixed

Comment: Looks great thanks. I need to explore it some more because besides `/boot` it's listing recursively and including `/boot/grub` and then `/boot/grub/i386-pc`. Also it isn't sorting by name. I don't want you to waste time though, I'll learn about the `find` command on my own time. Learning something everyday and loving the power of Linux.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix find never sorts by name. Your best bet is to pass it to `sort` and use `/` as sort's field separator

Comment: I was wrong about the sorting it seems just fine as show in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843197/what-are-kernel-version-number-components-w-x-yy-zzz-called because 3.2 kernel was added last but shows up sorted ok. Also using /boot/vm* solves the /boot/grub... recurssive listing problem. So all is good - thanks again.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix don't rely on find's sorting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47639/discussion-between-wineunuuchs2unix-and-muru).

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted muru's answer as it correctly shows how to find a file's last access time. However when grub mounts the kernel it is in `ro` read-only mode so the last access time is not updated.

Furthermore when you run `update-initramfs -u -k all` the file `initrd.img` is updated with current time for all kernels even though it hasn't been booted today.

When installing a new kernel the all kernel files `system.map-w.x.yy-zzz` are accessed even though it hasn't been booted today.

To correctly record when a kernel was last booted using sudo powers create a file like this in `/etc/cron.d/`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot   root    touch "/boot/vmlinuz-"`uname -r`
```

Now when listing files in `/boot` using muru's answer `vmlinuz-x.w.yy-zzz` will display when that kernel was last booted.