# apt-get clean does not clean

Tags: apt, cleanup

I have ubuntu 18.04, trying to upgrade to 18.10 but disk only has 2,8GB free.
I see I have 398MB in `var/lib/apt/lists` which seems really too much.

I ran `sudo apt-get clean` but it does literally nothing. 
Also tried BleachBit but the lists are still there.

What is the right way to clean that? Or maybe shouldn't I do that at all?

Thank you!

Chiara

Comment: Can you please try `sudo apt autoremove` and see if that helps? You will probably need to reboot once before upgrading. If that works, your question is a probably duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering! I tried but nothing, it says 0 updated, 0 installed, 0 to be removed

Answer (score 0):

**Don't Delete.** 
These are lists of packages available, if you delete them you won't be able to install anything. Unless you make them again by `apt update` and then same size of space will be needed.

If you have extra kernels

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l|egrep 'linux-image-[0-9]|linux-headers-[0-9]'|awk '{print $3,$2}'|grep -v `uname -r|cut -f1,2 -d"-"`|sort -nr|tail -n +4|awk '{ print $2}')
```

may clear some space.

Comment: Thank you! I already purged old kernels.. so I should consider 398MB of package lists normal?