# Can't upgrade ubuntu due to low space on '/'

Tags: disk-usage, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I was trying to upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. While trying to upgrade I encountered the following error.

`the upgrade has aborted. the upgrade needs a total of free space on disk '/'`

I found a similar situation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot) but the partition in question is different. 
The output from `df-h` is as follows;

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           774M  2.1M  771M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   15G   12G  2.5G  83% /
tmpfs           3.8G  125M  3.7G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop4      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop1       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/495
/dev/loop2      243M  243M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/27
/dev/loop3      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop5      4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/704
/dev/loop6       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop7       49M   49M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/loop9      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop8       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop10      26M   26M     0 100% /snap/heroku/3883
/dev/loop11      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop13     2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/730
/dev/loop12     157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop14      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop15      94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop16      25M   25M     0 100% /snap/heroku/3881
/dev/loop17     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop18      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop19     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
/dev/loop20     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/92
/dev/nvme0n1p7   78G   14G   60G  19% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   66M  191M  26% /boot/efi
tmpfs           774M   16K  774M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           774M   48K  773M   1% /run/user/1000
```

How do I fix this issue? 
Note: I am dual booting Ubuntu with Widows. The goal is to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.

Comment: You just need to clear some space on /. You have 12 GB of data on there, perhaps remove some downloads or uninstall something? 5GB should be enough space for the upgrade.

Comment: You won't be able to upgrade until 20.04.1 is released in July... either backup/delete some stuff from /, or edit your disk partitions and take 10G from /home and add it to /.