# problem updating

Tags: boot, kernel

when I open the software updater this message opens up:
***not enough free space
The upgrade needs a total of 136 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 45.2 M of disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt autoremove', and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your initramfs.***

*sudo autoremove* doesn't work.

what should I do?

thanks and regards

In response to the comments:

Here it is **ls /boot**:

```
config-4.15.0-144-generic      memtest86+.elf
config-5.4.0-74-generic        memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                           System.map-4.15.0-144-generic
initrd.img                     System.map-5.4.0-74-generic
initrd.img-4.15.0-144-generic  vmlinuz
initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic    vmlinuz-4.15.0-144-generic
initrd.img.old                 vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic
lost+found                     vmlinuz.old
memtest86+.bin
```

and here **df /h**:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        388M  1.8M  386M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  913G  9.6G  857G   2% /
tmpfs                        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    236M  137M   87M  62% /boot
tmpfs                        388M   32K  388M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Hi @alberto: can you post "ls /boot" and also "df -h"?

Comment: What you should do depends upon the skills you have. A user with intermediate skills can troubleshoot to see if anything unnecessary is taking up space in /boot. If nothing is found, they can look up how to back up their data, then re-partition to make a larger /boot partition. A user who isn't willing or able to do that must back up their data and reinstall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't upgrade due to low disk space on /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot)