# Is there a fix to this ridiculous boot size problem?

Tags: boot, 23.04

"[image]"

The upgrade needs a total of 151 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 86,2 M of disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt autoremove', and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your initramfs.

this mess has followed Ubuntu for years now, small /boot partition, and autoremove suggestion that does not help.

23.04 now .. is there a proper fix to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't upgrade due to low disk space on /boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/142926/)

Comment: Evidently, the separate `/boot` partition was created too small. Reinstalling with a properly sized `/boot` or simply not having a separate `/boot` partition is the recommended way to go.

Comment: "*[T]his mess has followed Ubuntu for years now*:" There have historically been several different causes, most fixed years ago. It's unclear which cause you have, so we cannot determine if your problem is one of those, or if your problem is self-inflicted. That happens too.