# Is this command to remove old kernels safe to use?

Tags: package-management, security, command-line

While browsing the internet for Ubuntu articles, I came across this command:

```
sudo dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

The author said that this is a single line command which will **delete all the previous versions of Linux, leaving only the current one**!

I'm actually looking for such a command, but I'm not so sure on how safe this is. I'd like to know:

- Whether it is safe to execute this command?
- How does this command work? i.e. explanation of small parts of such a big command
- If this command serves some different purpose, then what would be the correct command to achieve what the author claims it to do?

I become very confused and frustrated when I try to infer out all by myself. How does this command work for it contains numerous `/`, `|`, `\`, `*`, and `^` characters which are hard to Google for.

I am looking for a *step by step translation & explanation* for this command which I was unable to find across the internet!

Comment: This does not seem to be the same command you quote, but I have been using the command in http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/ to remove old kernels without any issues. This page also explains what the command does.

Comment: @UriHerrera `apt-get autoremove` doesn't suggest any removals of older kernels for me. If I don't delete them, they'll just pile up till my `/boot` is out of space and updates fail. Do you have a reference for it about that it should do this?

Comment: It does for me,  whenever there's a new update for the kernel, it says afterwards the following packages etc, are no longer required  and it lists the previous kernel that I had.

Comment: My answer was deleted by a moderator, so I comment here: See [this article](http://markmcb.com/2013/02/04/cleanup-unused-linux-kernels-in-ubuntu/) for explanation of the script. I don't see why one part of the script is `s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/` instead of simply `s/^[^ ]*  \([^ ]*\).*/\1/`. The script is not very robust or elegant. For example why check for current kernel before extracting the package name from the output? As for an alternative, `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` purges most old kernels in some latest release of Ubuntu like Xubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### I'd say: don't use it in the current form

1. It makes changes without asking you. The `apt-get -y purge` part allows the one-liner to start executing purging packages, without your confirmation. If any error in the script exists, then you could be *screwed*.
2. No source, no author given. The source of it makes a difference here. In case it would come from a thoroughly tested system package we can trace the testing being done onto it. From a random source, we can't trust it.
3. `dpkg -l` runs fine without `sudo`. I don't see why the original author thought this was necessary.

#### Use common sense

Remove the harmful parts and leave out anything that runs as root.

For example, cut it down to this:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
```

which just *only outputs stuff* and runs *with regular user permissions*. Once you agree with these kernels to be removed, you can *append* `| xargs sudo apt-get purge` yourself. It's without the `-y` option, intentionally, so you'll be asked for confirmation on the changes about to be made to your system.

#### Explanation

- `dpkg -l` Outputs the list of all packages. In this case it will only list packages *starting* with `linux-` as the name.
- `|` (a pipe) pipes the output of the command on the left (we call that `stdout`) to the input of the command on the right (we call that `stdin`).
- `sed` is a tool to manipulate strings using *regular expressions*. In this case it manipulates the output of the command on the left of the pipe and filters for installed packages (relying on the `ii` as given by `dpkg`). It is even being nested in this case. It would be too hard to explain the whole use of `sed` here, as its use is very complicated with the complex regular expressions. (the `\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)"` is an example of a regular expression.
- [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are very widely used to find matches based on the expression they represent. `\1` is the replacement reference to do a sort of universal search-and-replace (referencing to the first 'hit' with `1`). The regular expression themselves can't do any harm. However, if they manipulate the input in a wrong way, they can have you remove the wrong packages or even do shell injection. In this case it looks like a way to find the name of the kernel package based on the version provided by `uname -r`.
- `uname -r` outputs the current version of the kernel running.
- `xargs` appends the lines of the input left of the pipe as arguments to the command. In this case, the kernel versions on each line are converted to a horizontal space-separated list and appended to the `sudo apt-get` command.
- `sudo apt-get -y purge [packagename]` purges (removes everything) of the packages given (as arguments).

#### Alternatives

Quite some question are probably already asked about this. Relevant ones I found so far:

- [How to "clean" previous kernels after update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65096/how-to-clean-previous-kernels-after-update)
- [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)
- From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196437/88802), the following command seems to do the same in a much safer and more common way:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge $( dpkg --list | grep -P -o "linux-image-\d\S+" | grep -v $(uname -r | grep -P -o ".+\d") )
  ```

Comment: what shall be the breakup of the scary looking node of this command  which is something like this /\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/

Comment: will the above said command in this answer clear old kernels gracefully ?? or still apt-get autoremove is better ??

Comment: @Z9iT Those are regular expressions. They're used to find matches based on the *expression* they represent and the `\1` is the replacement control to do a sort of universal search-and-replace. For removal of any package I've expressed myself clear in my answer (being my opinion): use common sense. Don't let a script do changes to your system automatically. Verify what it would do. Always.

Comment: The alternative you feature does not purge respective linux-header packages.

Comment: Then just do an apt-get autoremove, which should detect those headers are no longer needed.

Answer (score 7):

You asked for a step-by-step explanation so here goes:

```
sudo dpkg -l 'linux-*'
```

Lists packages starting with `linux-` in the package name

```
| sed
```

and pipe the list into `sed`

```
"s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
```

which will use a very complicated regular expression to edit the list

```
| xargs
```

which will pipe the new list into `xargs`, which will send it as an argument to

```
sudo apt-get -y purge
```

which will purge those packages without giving you a chance to change your mind.

Or perhaps it's more accurate to say it will send that list into the purge command and leave it at that. Whether or not anything is purged — and importantly — exactly *what is purged* depends on the ouput of the previous commands.

Is it safe? In this case that all depends on how well the author of the post where you found it understands regular expressions and `sed` syntax. And there are whole books on both of those topics.

Answer (score 6):

I started by dissecting the commands, reading the `man` page for each.

- `dpkg -l`: list pacakges, so `dpkg -l linux-*` would list all packages that started with `linux-` (usually kernels).
- `sed`: The output of `dpkg -l linux-*` is piped to `sed` with several regular expressions which `sed` decodes.
- `uname -r` `uname`prints system information

> uname - print system information

The `-r` handle specifically prints kernel releases:

> -r, --kernel-release print the kernel release

The output of `uname -r` is then piped to `sed` with more regular expressions, the output of which is passed to `xargs`

So `xargs` translates the `sed` output into package names and passes them onto `sudo apt-get purge -y` which automatically answers 'yes' to all prompts:

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>              Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run
>              non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying
>              to install a unauthenticated package or removing an essential package occurs then
>              apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Altogether it seems this command *will* do what you want, though to know for sure we'd have to translate `sed`'s regular expressions.

I just ran:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
```

here is a screenshot:

[image]

All old kernel versions iirc.

Comment: what's the workout to translate this sed's expression ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand it right now, might take we a while ;)

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/712680/21005).

Comment: @Z9iT I was too lazy to copy the explanation of the script from the linked article to the answer, so I guess that is why Seth deleted my answer. But I think the linked article is what you were looking for from the Internet. I also told you a safer way to remove old kernels, though it keeps 2-3 kernels just in case, and may not work in all current Ubuntu releases yet.

Comment: @jarno I deleted it because Z9iT was asking about a *specific* command, not a safe way to remove old kernels. That might still be relevant, but in a comment, not an answer :) (like you did)

Comment: @Z9iT, oh, there is a bug (#1440608) in removing of kernels by `apt-get autoremove`, so it may leave only one kernel installed.

Comment: @Z9iT, it is true that command `apt-get autoremove --purge` may remove also some other unneeded packages, but is that bad? I think this question was more about explaining the given script. There are other questions about removing extra kernels. And I have an answer [there](http://askubuntu.com/a/571360/21005).

Answer (score 0):

A less dangerous version of this script that removes unused and out of date kernels matches for `rc` in the beginning of a line of the `dpkg` output, instead of `ii`. (See https://askubuntu.com/a/18807/220802 for an explanation of these flags.) In my case this exactly matches all kernel packages which are not protected by `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels`.

For example:

```
# sed -n '/to keep/,$p' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels
# Kernel versions list to keep:
5.4.0-58.64
5.4.0-60.67
# Kernel packages (version part) to protect:
5\.4\.0-58-generic
5\.4\.0-60-generic
*/
```

and

```
# dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^rc/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic
linux-image-5.3.0-19-generic
linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-21-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-28-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-31-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic
linux-modules-5.3.0-18-generic
linux-modules-5.3.0-19-generic
linux-modules-5.3.0-45-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-21-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-28-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-31-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-33-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-40-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-48-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-52-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-53-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-18-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-19-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-21-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-28-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-31-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-40-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-48-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-52-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic
```

which you can pipe to `| xargs apt purge -y` now. Please note that omitting the `-y` flag will result in abortion of the operation.

Then you can check your `/boot` directory for further remnants of older kernels. In my case there were more files hanging around that were not tracked by `apt` anymore, which were removed with `ls /boot/*-5.4.0-{00..56}* 2>/dev/null` being heartfully piped to `| xargs rm -rf`.