# When I boot my laptop multiple Ubuntu is listing on grub

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2

This is my grub when I bootup my laptop. Is multiple installation done? If yes then how to delete the second Ubuntu (/dev/sda8)? I installed Ubuntu with windows 10. I want to remove the second Ubuntu (/dev/sda8)

[my grub screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRQCq.jpg)

Comment: What second Ubuntu? I can only see one Ubuntu on /dev/sda8. What you may see in Grub menu is multiple kernels. There are multiple questions here on the topic of removing them, just search. http://askubuntu.com/questions/590673/why-doesnt-ubuntu-remove-old-kernels-automatically

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if it works, I wouldn't go messing around with it. I dual boot Linux mint with Windows and the amount of times I've broken the boot process while trying to edit and change things is just ridiculous. Find whichever ones work and just use those :).

Comment: now both are working fine.But i don't need the second ubuntu. which is wasting 12 GB of my hard disk. i checked in disks applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know how you installed those I also have to recommend to be cautious but in general you can use gparted to delete a partition such as sda8 in your case. Make sure the installation of Ubuntu you intend to use doesn't depend on it though. Definitely back up everything before. Worst case you create an Ubuntu usb and reinstall and choose the something different option when it comes to formating your disk. There you can delete all your Ubuntu partitions and create new ones.

Comment: lemme check gparted.but i scare that will lost windows and linux!!

Comment: Definitely make backups of both. Linux is not a big problem if you loose it since it's free but windows is always a hassle with activation (I hear, never actually reinstalled windows myself). When you check out gparted, make sure you know what is on each of the partitions. If you delete a partition with linux on it (in your case probably sda8), that should not harm windows at all. I have done that recently switching from mint to ubuntu.