# How can I saftly delete the old kernel version from the /boot partition?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, bash, kernel, boot-partition

I am not so into **Linux** and I have the following problem related to the fact that my **/boot** partition seems to be full and it seems to cause a problem trying to install a program.

I try to explain in detail my doubts because I am not so into system engineering (I am a software developer).

1) Performing the **lsblk** statment lists information about all available or the specified block devices.

Empirically I think that it should show the list of all the **partitions/mounted disks** or something like this. What exactly means with the terms **block devices**?

So if I perform this statment on my **Ubuntu** system I obtain:

```
root@MyServer-VPS:~# lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0              2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda              8:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─sda1           8:1    0  476M  0 part /boot
├─sda2           8:2    0    1K  0 part
├─sda3           8:3    0   10G  0 part
│ └─vg-lv_root 252:0    0 18.6G  0 lvm  /
└─sda5           8:5    0  9.5G  0 part
  ├─vg-lv_root 252:0    0 18.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg-lv_swap 252:1    0  952M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0             11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

So what is the difference between **disk**, **part** (it should be a partition of the parent disk), **lvm** and **rom**?

A specific partition is **boot**, this one:

```
sda1           8:1    0  476M  0 part /boot
```

that is a **sda** disk partition.

From what I know it should contains the **Linux Kernel downloaded versions**. Is it?

Ok, the mount point is **/boot** so I think that it is the **/boot** directory into my system (is it?), this is the content:

```
root@MyServer-VPS:/boot# ls
abi-4.4.0-21-generic  config-4.4.0-21-generic  grub                         System.map-4.4.0-21-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
abi-4.4.0-31-generic  config-4.4.0-31-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic  System.map-4.4.0-31-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
abi-4.4.0-34-generic  config-4.4.0-34-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic  System.map-4.4.0-34-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
abi-4.4.0-38-generic  config-4.4.0-38-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic  System.map-4.4.0-38-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
abi-4.4.0-42-generic  config-4.4.0-42-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic  System.map-4.4.0-42-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic
abi-4.4.0-45-generic  config-4.4.0-45-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic  System.map-4.4.0-45-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
abi-4.4.0-47-generic  config-4.4.0-47-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic  System.map-4.4.0-47-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
abi-4.4.0-51-generic  config-4.4.0-51-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic  System.map-4.4.0-51-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
abi-4.4.0-53-generic  config-4.4.0-53-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic  System.map-4.4.0-53-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
abi-4.4.0-57-generic  config-4.4.0-57-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic  System.map-4.4.0-57-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
abi-4.4.0-59-generic  config-4.4.0-59-generic  lost+found                   System.map-4.4.0-59-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
```

So what these contents exactly represents? Are the differents Linux kernel versions downloaded on this system?

What are the difference between the **abi-**, **config-**, **initrd.img-**, **System.map-** and **vmlinuz-4** files?

**How can I detect the used kernel version?**

2) Performing the **df -h** statment I obtain this output:

```
root@MyServer-VPS:~# df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    477M     0  477M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   100M   16M   84M  16% /run
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root   19G   12G  6.3G  64% /
tmpfs                   497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               461M  458M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

In particular I have that:

```
/dev/sda1               461M  458M     0 100% /boot
```

So it means that my **/boot** partition is completly full?

My problem is: can I saftly deetect delete all the old kernel version (the not used one) to free up space in the **/boot** ?

How can I do it?

Comment: This is odd. Ubuntu 16.04 removes old kernels by default. Are you sure it's Ubuntu, and not one of the odd ball derivatives?

Comment: @mikewhatever Ubuntu 16.04 does NOT remove any kernels unless you run `apt autoremove`.

Comment: In my experience Ubuntu 16.04 does NOT remove old kernels by default, and there are good reasons for that discussed  [here] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/590673/why-doesnt-ubuntu-remove-old-kernels-automatically) there are a number of ways to do [this type of maintenance] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) Unfortunately there are a lot of ways to do this, and coming up with a system that works for you requires a lot reading and thought on on the subject. There should really be an agreed upon best practice for this problem.

Comment: Autoremove will remove them all but the current, and previous kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6: An added feature in 16.04 does the equivalent of running autoremove daily, see /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades, near line 40.

Comment: @mikewhatever: The kernel apt-marking for autoremove is fragile by design, and can be undone by users several possible ways. Header packages, for example often prevent kernel-image autoremove

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command :

```
uname -a
```

to see which kernel you are currently using.
Then you can use the command :

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

to see which older kernels you can safely remove.

Since removing older kernels might still involve already having some free space in /boot (Yes, a catch22 situation) you could work around that by using the ">" sign to first zero out the older kernels about which you are sure you won't be using them.

For example :

```
sudo bash
> /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
> /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
exit
```

After this freeing up space in /boot, it becomes easier to remove older kernels with apt-get or dpkg commands.

I've used this method in the past successfully, because manually removing kernels in /boot/ with the rm command, will likely lead to problems with apt-get/dpkg if you want to use the "apt-get autoremove --purge" command.